# Proof and explanation that $\gcd(A, B) = \gcd(B, A \mod B)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

First I'm not studying mathematics and so I need the simplest answer as possible(any example will be appreciated). I was reading a book about cryptography and saw the following equation
$$\gcd(A, B) = \gcd(B, A  \bmod B)$$which I can't understand at all. But I understand this equation if someone can use it to give a simple answer
$$\gcd(A, B) = \gcd(B, A  - B)$$

Comment: This is a very common algorithm known as the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). Further reading on the wikipedia page may answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: Repeat your second step until you are left with a remainder between $0$ and $B-1$

Comment: @Henry so because ```gcd(a, b) = gcd(a, a-b)``` this means that ```gcd(a, b) = gcd(a, a mod b)```

Comment: If you can subtract $B$ from $A$ without changing the $\gcd$, then you can subtract any multiple of $B$. You might as well subtract the multiple of $B$ that leaves the remainder.

Comment: @runway44 It isn't *that* trivial.

Comment: assume the bigger number $B$ to be $ B = mA + q $ where $ m \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $ q \lt A $.